# How to set Retry Interval time when using SeekToCurrentErrorHandler in spring kafka

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am handling the container listener errors using SeekToCurrentErrorHandler in the spring-boot application. I want to set the retry interval if an exception occurred it should wait some certain time and retry until the max attempts.

I have tried adding RetryTemplate by setting up a backup policy. but it didn't work as excepted. when the error occurs max attempts time it will call SeekToCurrentErrorHandler 2 times.

```
@Bean
    public RetryPolicy retryPolicy() {
        SimpleRetryPolicy simpleRetryPolicy = new SimpleRetryPolicy();
        simpleRetryPolicy.setMaxAttempts(retryMaxAttempts);
        return simpleRetryPolicy;
    }


    @Bean
    public BackOffPolicy backOffPolicy() {
        FixedBackOffPolicy backOffPolicy = new FixedBackOffPolicy();
        backOffPolicy.setBackOffPeriod(retryInterval);
        return backOffPolicy;
    }


    @Bean
    public RetryTemplate retryTemplate() {
        RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new RetryTemplate();
        retryTemplate.setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy());
        retryTemplate.setBackOffPolicy(backOffPolicy());
        return retryTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String>> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(
            ChainedKafkaTransactionManager<String, String> chainedTM) {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        factory.setConcurrency(concurrency);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setPollTimeout(pollTimeout);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setSyncCommits(true);
    // ------->>     factory.setRetryTemplate(retryTemplate());
        factory.getContainerProperties().setAckOnError(false);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setTransactionManager(chainedTM);
        SeekToCurrentErrorHandler errorHandler = new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler((record, exception) -> {
        // handle errors 
        }, retryMaxAttempts);
        factory.setErrorHandler(errorHandler);
        log.debug("Kafka Receiver Config kafkaListenerContainerFactory created");
        return factory;
    }
```

How to set retry Interval time when using the SeekToCurrentErrorHandler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a [new feature in the next release (2.3)](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/pull/1185).

You can, however, do it with a retry template but the total number of attempts will be the multiple of the two properties.

Comment: Thanks @GaryRussell. When we can expect  to release?

Comment: It's available now in 2.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT; the release candidate is currently scheduled for September 5 and 2.3.0.RELEASE is currently scheduled for September 19.

Comment: @GaryRussell Is it that when `RetryTemplate` and `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler` should NOT be used at the same time and we should choose only ONE of them?

Comment: Yes; now that the STCEH supports back off and exception classification, it is preferred over using the `RetryTemplate`.

Comment: @GaryRussell let's say i have configured STCEH with 2 hr as interval and attempts 3. So will my kafka consumer be able to consume next messages and retry failed message after interval i have defined in STCEH ?

Comment: No; the STCEH suspends the consumer thread for the duration. You need to use the Non-Blocking retry feature for that, where the failed record is written to a different topic so we can continue to process from the main one. https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#retry-topic I see that you are relatively new here; you should not ask new questions in comments on old answers - it doesn't help people find answers to questions.